# how to assign a key (QtCore.Qt.Key_1) to a button in python. a numeric pad

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt4, numpad

i have this [numpad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGnZU.png), i would like to make every numbered button to write its coresponding number on the line above. For example if i enter 1234 by presing on the buttons the same sequence to be displayed on the line. i'm using pyqt4 with qt designer.
   The line above is a QlineEdit, i import the .ui file directly in the python script i don't convert it using pyuic4. can someone help me find a solution to this? i'm m new to python i started 3 month ago. Thank you

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("ui/sales_window.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete ui file.

Comment: i cant upload it, it has 30000+characters, and this page has a limit on 30k

Comment: Okay. You could use a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) link, instead.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ujsPewCa here is the ui file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to create a button-group for the number-pad.

In Qt Designer, click on one of the buttons, then Ctrl+click all the other buttons in the number-pad so that they are all selected (twelve buttons in all). Now right-click one of the buttons and select **Assign to button group > New button group** from the menu. Then save the ui file.

You can now add a handler to your main script to control the buttons:

```
class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("aaa.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.barcode_src_line.setReadOnly(True)
        self.buttonGroup.buttonClicked.connect(self.handleButtons)

    def handleButtons(self, button):
        char = str(button.text())
        if char == 'C':
            self.barcode_src_line.clear()
        else:
            text = str(self.barcode_src_line.text()) or '0'
            if char != '.' or '.' not in text:
                if text != '0' or char == '.':
                    text += char
                else:
                    text = char
                self.barcode_src_line.setText(text)
```

This will work like a normal calculator. If you want different behaviour, you can of course re-write `handleButtons` in any way you like.

Comment: 1000 thanks, if you ever pass my town i will buy you some drinks. the code works as i need it to do. i am very gratefull

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Calculator Builder example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-calculatorbuilder-example.html) in Qt's documentation it explains how you can handle ui loaded files when you don't use uic on them.

It's in C++ but shows the basic technique.

Comment: thanks for the link, the problem is i dont know C++, i will try to study your link, but i would apreciate if you could start me with an example in python. and btw the link shows a calculator, i dont need a calculator this keyboard will input a numeric string.